# background animation not clipped on rounded corners container

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, core-animation

I have a created a cool theme for checkboxes which renders them as *iOS-5* style buttons with animation, all in CSS, but I have this annoying problem with the background not being clipped on webkit for the rounded corners. I know this **bug** is because clipping container has `position` which causes the thing, but I can't think of any way to fix this..

Does someone knows how to deal with this issue?
I have dug into this bug didn't find anything useful. 10x!

**[CHECK THE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XCKau/)** (works great on Firefox)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is better than before... But still not perfect.

http://jsfiddle.net/XCKau/1/

Add a border-radius to the label:before and label:after and hide the checkbox:

```
.togglebox label::before{
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
}
.togglebox label::after{
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}
input[type=checkbox]{
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Why downvote? I wrote that it's not perfect but still better than yours.

Comment: because obviously I have already thought about this and dismissed the idea..no offenses mate, I just felt like getting spit on my face, offering me such solution is disrespectful to my CSS skills and obviously the problem at hand is much greater than rounding some corners of internal elements... :)

Comment: "obviously" not everyone is aware of your css-skills ;) if you already tried that, I'm sorry, but I just wanted to help out.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this does work:

```
.togglebox label::before {
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
}

.togglebox label::after {
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}
```

I'd also make a small modification to the 'checked' state:

```
.togglebox input:checked ~ label { left: -61px }
```

But the problem is that the check box becomes visible then. Adding something simple like:

```
#chkbx {position: absolute; left: 10px;}
```

should solve that problem.

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XCKau/2/

I advise you to not put a display: none; on the input! Just to be sure. - Just tested it: when it's NOT in `display: none;` people using IE8 can still use the check box. If you do use it, they wouldn't be able to 'check' anything.

Comment: Still not perfect in my browser.

How about `visibility:hidden;` for hiding the checkbox? does that work?

Comment: @Alex what browser is that? I've tested my jsfiddle on every major browser and it works (excl. <IE9). Why would you need to hide it? There's no need to hide it! It lies 'under' the rest.

vsync why the down rate? The problem is solved, and you are using CSS3 yourself. What's the problem?

Comment: To be quite honest: I don't think you are reaching the audience you can get to. The share of IE is still quite large, so the basic functionality should be accessible to ANYONE.

Comment: @BramVanroy hiding is prettier than just putting it under the other elements in my opinion.

This is how it looks in my Chrome, I hope you see what I meant with "not perfect": http://imgur.com/aEsav

Comment: But the problem is that when a user is not using a css/css3 capable device, it can't just check the box because it is hidden. If you just hide it beneath the css elements, it might still show up (as it does in IE8). And ah, I see what you mean. I don't know how to solve that right now.

Comment: Okay, now I see your point. Thanks! But, I think the elements that are over the checkbox are positioned with css2? So the checkbox is hidden anyway, no matter if the browser supports css3 or not. However, I see your point.

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but for some reason IE8 still displays the checkbox and it isn't hidden (as you can see [here](http://i41.tinypic.com/20a42vo.png)). I would just do this with conditional stylesheets and indeed hide it in the css3 stylesheet as you said.